# Не присваивается значение к переменной JS

Tags: javascript, функции, overflow

```
function loop(value, fPredicate, fUpdate, fBody) {
    for (value; fPredicate(value); value = fUpdate(value))
    {
        fBody(value);
    }
}

loop(0, n => n < 3, n => n++, console.log);
```

`value = fUpdate(value)`

Проблема: значение value не обновляется, происходит переполнение стека.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените `n => n++` на `n => ++n`: постинкремент сначала возвращает значение переменной, а потом увеличивает её. И так как вы используете в функциях не одну и ту же переменную, а копируемое из неё значение, последующее изменение нигде не сохраняется.

Comment: А лучше `n => n + 1` что бы инкремент не вводил в заблуждение